# Dropdownlist looses value during autopostback

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, autopostback

I have a couple of straightforward dropdownlists. The first is bound by a linqdatsource in the html with autopostback set to true. The selection of the first determines the data in the second. When I select an item in the first, the selectedindexChanged event fires; however, the selected value is always the first item in the list and the list then re-binds and reverts to its default state. Do I have to bind it in code-behind to prevent this?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dd_shirtcolor" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select Color" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server"
    ContextTypeName="IPC.IPCDataDataContext" EntityTypeName=""
    TableName="Shirts" Where="IsActive == @IsActive">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="true" Name="IsActive" Type="Boolean" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Comment: I recently had a similar problem with DropDownLists like this. How do you determine the values in `dd_shirtcolor`? Is it in the code behind?

Comment: That list is bound in the code-behind during the selectedindexchanged event of the dd_shirtlist control. I don't have anything in the load event

Comment: I believe the problem may lie in that code. Could you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17175223/edit) your post and show us what happens during that event?

Comment: I had remarked that code out with no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some alternatives to managing cascading drop down lists yourself are:

ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit:
[ASP.NET AJAX Cascading Drop Down](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/cascadingdropdown/cascadingdropdown.aspx)

Cascading Drop Down Using ASP.NET and jQuery:
[Cascading Drop Down Using ASP.NET And jQuery](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/97/Cascading-DropDownLists-with-jQuery-and-ASP.NET)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have ViewState enabled so it can populate the list before it "selects" the item. 
Also, make sure you don't repopulate in Page_Load and lose the selected value.
eg.
if (!IsPostback) { // Populate }

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this problem by binding the dropdown in the code behind in page_init method with the proper !postback conditional instead of using the linqdatasource to bind it. I am still not sure what was causing it however.